# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis2/AxisFault When axis2-kernel-1.5.4.jar is in the class path

Tags: java, windows, apache-axis

I have a jar file with a main() statement that instantiates and calls an [axis2](http://axis.apache.org/) web service stub. It cannot seem to find org.apache.axis2.AxisFault despite it being on my classpath. I am running 1.6.0_25 on windows 7. My command is as follows:

```
java -classpath "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\axis2-1.5.4\lib\axis2-kernel-1.5.4.jar" -jar .\build\lib\SoapClient-test-client.jar
```

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis2/AxisFault
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-jar` makes java ignore any `-cp` jars.  Adjust the Class-Path in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks, So far my classpath is `<attribute name="Class-Path" value="axiom-api-1.2.10.jar axiom-impl-1.2.10.jar axis2-kernel-1.5.4.jar axis2-adb-1.5.4.jar axis2-transport-http-1.5.4.jar axis2-transport-local-1.5.4.jar commons-logging-1.1.1.jar log4j-1.2.15.jar neethi-2.0.4.jar wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar XmlSchema-1.4.3.jar"/>` and growing!

Comment: ant has facilities for getting the names for all files in a folder.   If you know where your jars are, you can use that to compute this value.